# DownloadManager: understand retry policy and error codes

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-download-manager

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#COLUMN_REASON), if download is failed due to http error - the `COLUMN_REASON` should hold the specific http error code.

the problem I'm having is that in practice, the only reason value I see when download fail is [`ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR)

also, I see in logcat the actual failure http code in runtime, when the download is being stopped and re-try, but I don't see any way to get it from the download manager.

**is it possible to get somehow this http code?**

I'm using broadcast receiver to handle [`ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) , but I don't see any way to listen to download paused, and I'm getting a feeling that if I'll query download manager failure reason between the retry attempts it does - then I'll get the actual status code.

is it possible to listen to "download pause" event without querying constantly the download manager?

I would expect that will be such broadcast.

the questions that I'd love to finally get answers to are:

- is it possible to listen to "download pause" event without querying constantly the download manager, and without active listener to the content resolver?
- is download manager (on API level 16+) supports https (ssl) ?
- what exactly is download manager retry policy? can I change it default retry policy?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: agree, but give me a break... :->   this questions are actually more important to me then the original question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> is it possible to get somehow this http code?

Currently, no. The DownloadManager reports a `STATUS_SUCCESSFUL` even when a download failed, for example because the url/file was not found (HTTP 404) (this is a bug).
Also see [DownloadManager sends STATUS_SUCCESSFUL for failed download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852821/downloadmanager-sends-status-successful-for-failed-download)

I know it's a relatively old thread but that issue still remains. I tested it 5 minutes ago and it still doesn't work properly.

---

> is it possible to listen to "download pause" event without querying constantly the download manager?

Weirdly, no. The only available "events" to listen for are:
[image]

To get around this, you have to query the status yourself every X time by checking

```
if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

---

> is download manager (on API level 16+) supports https (ssl) ?

It used to not support https (read more in [Android DownloadManager and SSL (https)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106155/android-downloadmanager-and-ssl-https)), however it does now. You can simply verify by trying to retrieve a file from a https origin, for example `https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3794/mixed_content_webconsole.jpg`. You will see that it retrieves the file fine.

---

> what exactly is download manager retry policy? can I change it default retry policy?

It is currently not possible to change the retry 'policy'. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) and you will find there are no methods or properties regarding this functionality.

Regarding the default retry policy, useful information can be found in the following package: [com.android.providers.downloads.Constants](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/providers/downloads/Constants.java?av=f). This links to the 5.1.1 version, if you need the information for another version you can manually navigate to that. For example [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/providers/downloads/Constants.java?av=f) is the information for android 4.0.1 (the retry policy values are the same as in 5.1.1).

It states:

> The number of times that the download manager will retry its network operations when no progress is happening before it gives up.
>
> ```
> public static final int MAX_RETRIES = 5;
> ```
>
> The minimum amount of time that the download manager accepts for a Retry-After response header with a parameter in delta-seconds.
>
> ```
> public static final int MIN_RETRY_AFTER = 30; // 30s
> ```
>
> The maximum amount of time that the download manager accepts for a Retry-After response header with a parameter in delta-seconds.
>
> ```
> public static final int MAX_RETRY_AFTER = 24 * 60 * 60; // 24h
> ```

As you might have guessed, these are final (constant) and thus cannot be changed.

---

Conclusion: DownloadManager is pretty useful to do some basic downloading, but it's functionality is pretty limited.

<sub>I can suggest an alternative: there's a [downloadmanager](https://github.com/Trinea/android-common/blob/master/src/cn/trinea/android/common/util/DownloadManagerPro.java) in the android-common libary over at https://github.com/Trinea/android-common</sub>

<sub>I have not used it myself, but 2k+ stars on github usually means it's worth checking out.</sub>

Comment: It is still giving STATUS_SUCCESSFUL while file is not there at that url(error 404). Is it still a bug?