# How to use Android Download manager with https?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I was able to use DownloadManager to download HTTP request but I am unable to find any documentation/method regarding how can we use DownloadManager with HTTPS.

```
public long downloadFile(String fileUrl, String filename, String description, String token) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileUrl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filename))
        request.setTitle(filename);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(description))
        request.setDescription(description);

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    request.addRequestHeader("authorization", token);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    return mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference between HTTP and HTTPS downloading?

Comment: because I'm getting error "Trust anchor for certification path not found. download manager" if I pass HTTPS request to download manager.

Comment: look here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106155/android-downloadmanager-and-ssl-https` - possible duplicate

Comment: i had seen this but no reliable answer yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android DownloadManager and SSL (https)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106155/android-downloadmanager-and-ssl-https)